# inline element on same row: how can i do?

Tags: html, css

I've this code.

```
<div id="header">

    <p>Home</p>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>Home</p>
    <p>Home</p>

</div>
```

How can i display this element at center inline on same line? I tried

```
#header {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}
```

but dont'work

Comment: What means *"at center inline on same line?"*?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, If you don't want to change your markup.

```
#header{
    text-align:center;
}
#header p{
    display:inline; 
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7XMHf/)

Answer (score 1):

**Without changing the HTML markup** of `p` to `span` elements

<sub>One way is using `display:inline` for `p`: [demo](http://jsbin.com/ASojeNI/3/edit)</sub>

```
#header{
  text-align:center;
}
#header p{
  display:inline;
}
```

<sub>another, using `display:table`: [*demo*](http://jsbin.com/ASojeNI/4/edit)</sub>

```
#header{
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#header p{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `span` element example here : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/774fF/2/)

```
#header{
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;        
}
```

```
<div id="header">   
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>Home</span>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `inline` display should be applied to the elements you want to be displayed inline (i.e. the `<p>`). Also, a better alternative in my opinion would be to use `inline-block`. Which would conserve the `block` status of the `<p>`, but still make it `inline`.

```
#header {
    text-align: center; /* Don't forget, you're centering inline elements (i.e. text) */
}

#header p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `p` as inline-block implies the use of ugly hacks for old browsers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: It all depends on what you are doing. I am usually against changing elements' `display` value into something they were never meant to be. With HTML 5, we have semantic elements for practically everything. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

`Display:inline` is a good solution as others mentioned.

You can also try `float:left` for the same.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/h26Sk/1/)

```
#header p{
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```